# Visualizing a positive to negative metric

Tags: info-visualisation, metrics

I'm looking for a way to visualize (and hopefully simplify) a metric that can have one of the following values:

- High positive
- Medium positive
- Low positive
- Zero
- Low negative
- Medium negative
- High negative

What I have so far is this kind of bar:

[image]

One limitation is that the visualization cannot use different colors (such as green and red) as I already use colors in a different part of the screen that should have the main focus.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the thing/product that is being classified?

Comment: @rewobs it is correlation

Answer (score 1):

You can't use different colors, so you'll have to use shapes.
You know how some rating websites use $ = inexpensive and $$$ = expensive? What if you did something similar. Print just the outlines of + and -, and fill them in based on whether low, medium, or high correlation.

I think it'd also be helpful to print the spelled-out results in a light, thin font in case they still have trouble interpreting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some ideas playing with shapes, tints, high/low conventions, dirty/clean metaphors. Of course it will be easier if your metrics are numeric instead of conceptual. You could also place labels below/above, you could use grids to support the metaphor and so on, basically showing some wireframes in the hope they are of help for you

[image]